# layer.borderColor and more attributes aren't working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to modify a Button, and I created a custom class for a UIButton which has the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ButtonStyle: UIButton {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        self.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

But the button only isn't doing anything.

Comment: have you assign the class to button?

Comment: @Pushpa yes, I have assigned to it

Comment: What do you mean by "button only isn't doing anything" can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it would be helpfull!!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class BaseClass: NSObject {
 class func setButton(btn:UIButton,withColor:UIColor)->Void
    {
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        btn.backgroundColor = withColor

    }
}
```

And Call this method Where you want.

```
 BaseClass.setButton(buttonName, withColor: UIColor.greenColor())
```

And Set the outlet of button

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonName: UIButton!
```